# Automating KDE Plasma Settings

Tags: shell-script, display-settings

I have a dual-monitor setup, and I want games to appear on the second monitor (which has a higher resolution). Unfortunately, only a handful will allow for moving on the second monitor, and the rest will just stick with the resolutions from the first (Kwin rules don't help).

My current solution is to temporarily set the second monitor as primary whenever I'm playing a game. However, I wish to be able to automate this in a bash script, along with a few other tasks. Is there some API I need (perhaps via `dbus`?) or a configuration file I can change that would allow me to do this?